# datatables action column not working properly

Tags: jquery, datatables

Every time I click the next row, the function of the last row I clicked is executing again. For instance, if I click 'good' on the first row for type and then click 'bad' on the second row for type, it submits 'good' again unless I click 'bad' one more time (its like it needs to be double clicked). Not sure if it has anything to do with the onclick table row function as it is not specific to the element. Do I make it so that its clicking the element with a specific id?

Here is my code:

```
var table = $(‘#foobar’).DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: “Type” },
            { title: "Status" },
            { title: “Good”, defaultContent: '<a id=“good” onclick="good()"><i class="fa fa-check“></i></a> },           
       { title: “Bad”, defaultContent: '<a id=“bad” onclick="bad()"><i class="fa fa-times”></i></a> },    
     ]
        } );

           
function good(){

 $(‘#foobar tr').click( function () {
              let row = table.row( this ).data();
              let rowid = row[0];
              let row = table.row(this);
//here I would update some spreadsheet with "good" and it sometimes works depending on the clicks
              table.cell(row, 2).data("good").draw();

        } );

}


function bad(){

 $(‘#foobar tr').click( function () {
              let row = table.row( this ).data();
              let rowid = row[0];
              let row = table.row(this);
              //here I would update some spreadsheet with "bad" and it sometimes works depending on the clicks
              table.cell(row, 2).data("bad").draw();

        } );

}
```

Comment: The code in the question has some syntax issues - for example the use of `“` instead of `"`. And declaring the same variable more than once (e.g. `let row = ...`). I suspect these are from how you copy/pasted the code into the question (because it will not execute as written).

Comment: But the issue you are seeing is probably caused by the fact that your `good()` and `bad()` functions also register their own click events on the table rows: `$('#foobar tr').click( function () {...}`. That means, after the first "good" click and again after the first "bad" click, there will be additional competing events firing, every time you click anywhere in any row. I cannot suggest a fix for this, because I am not sure what the code is aiming to do.

Comment: @andrewjames it does appear that way that the events are being fired off simultaneously. How can I make sure only one is being fired off when clicked?

Comment: I provided some notes in an answer (too long to fit into a comment!). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking to do is something like this:

[image]

The values in the "Status" column are controlled by which link you click on - the "good" link or the "bad" link.

Here is a working demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dataSet = [ 
  [ "Foo Type", "not set" ],
  [ "Bar Type", "not set" ],
  [ "Baz Type", "not set" ]
];

var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

table = $('#foobar').DataTable( {
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { title: "Type" },
    { title: "Status" },
    { title: "Good", 
      "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
        console.log( 'in render function' );
        return '<a onclick="good(' + 
          meta.row + 
          ')"><i class="fa fa-check">click me</i></a>';
      }
    },
    { title: "Bad", 
      "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
        return '<a onclick="bad(' + 
          meta.row + 
          ')"><i class="fa fa-check">click me</i></a>';
      }
    }    
  ]
} );

} );

function good( row_idx ){
  table.cell(row_idx, 1).data("good").draw();
}


function bad( row_idx ){
  table.cell(row_idx, 1).data("bad").draw();
}


</script>
```

I replaced your `default` column values with `columns.render()` functions. These functions give you access to the row index number, using `meta.row` - which is what we pass to the revised `good()` and `bad()` functions.

The functions then update the 2nd column of that row with either "good" or "bad".

Note that a row index is based on the order in which data was initially provided to the DataTable - not the order of rows that you see when you look at the table (which may be different due to sorting).

If this is not exactly what you need, it should at least point you in the right direction (I think).